# Open SSMS automatically from C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, ssms

I have a WPF application with listbox in it and the listbox contains items whcih are the connection strings for the servers, like this

instance1\server1
instance2\server2
 so i have the below code this is just a sample

```
private void ListBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sli=ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(sli);
        }
```

so instead of showing message box i want to open a connection to the SSMS with the username and password provided, if ssms already open i dont want to open another SSMS if one is already open open the connection in that..how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the application with a set of command line parameters that will do this.  I don't think you can manipulate an existing instance though......maybe through powershell perhaps.

SSMS has a number of command line options which allow you to specify a number of things. These can be seen by executing the /? command. Here are the results of that command.

---

### Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

```
Usage:
sqlwb.exe [-S server_name[\instance_name]] [-d database] [-U user] [-P password] [-E] [file_name[, file_name]] [/?]

 [-S The name of the SQL Server instance to which to connect]
 [-d The name of the SQL Server database to which to connect]
 [-E] Use Windows Authentication to login to SQL Server
 [-U The name of the SQL Server login with which to connect]
 [-P The password associated with the login]
 [file_name[, file_name]] names of files to load
 [-nosplash] Supress splash screen
 [/?] Displays this usage information
---------------------------
OK   
----
```

---

Comment: so if lets say this opens up an instance of ssms can i assume that the next connection that i open from the listbox uses the already opened SSMS instance rather than opening another new one?..and also can i elminate some of the options like database and password?

Comment: My understanding is if you don't specify a database - it stays as master (default).  I believe it will create a new instance for each time you call it (same as clicking on the icon).  I am not sure if it supports using an existing instance.